# How can I fix the rotation angle of the camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've implemented a third-person camera, and when the camera's field of view is looking up or down, when the angle with the floor is more than 90 degrees, the screen momentarily turns 180 degrees horizontally.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float targetY;

    public float xRotMax;
    public float rotSpeed;
    public float scrollSpeed;

    public float distance;
    public float minDistance;
    public float maxDistance;

    private float xRot;
    private float yRot;
    private Vector3 targetPos;
    private Vector3 dir;

    private void Update()
    {
        xRot += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        yRot += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        distance += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * scrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        xRot = Mathf.Clamp(xRot, -xRotMax, xRotMax);
        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance, minDistance, maxDistance);

        targetPos = target.position + Vector3.up * targetY;

        dir = Quaternion.Euler(-xRot, yRot, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        transform.position = targetPos + dir * -distance;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.LookAt(targetPos);
    }
}
```

I want to create a limit so that when the camera looks up and down, it doesn't bend more than 90 degrees horizontally, so what should I do?

Comment: So, clamp your `xRot` to the desired range?

Answer (score 0):

Well, handling 3D rotation is hard using 3-dimensional vectors, which is why the majority of the 3D software uses quaternions to handle the rotation of a 3D object. And this can be one of the reasons why your camera is rotating 180 horizontally. The best practice is to clamp the rotation for the camera's x-axis ie. up and down the rotation. The following snippet should help.

```
float yRotationLimit = 70; //This should be lessthan or equal to 90 degrees.
....
....
....
yRot += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
yRot = Mathf.Clamp(yRot, -yRotationLimit, yRotationLimit);
```

Hope this helps let me know if there is anything else.